# how to deduplicate packpath / runtimepath?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, path, packages, init

**Problem:**

I noticed that my "&packpath" has some duplicates, I want to remove them.

**What I have tried:**

My viml knowledge is not very strong but I did manage to create a unique "List", but I am not sure how to turn that list back into the correct string without calling "!awk/!sed/!perl", I now think that perhaps there is a simpler "vim" way to do it? my example:

```
let newpackpath = string(uniq(split(&packpath, ',')))
```

Returns this string:

```
['/data/data/com.termux/files/home/conf/nvim', 
'/data/data/com.termux/files/home/data/nvim/site', 
'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/nvim/runtime', 
'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/nvim', 
'/data/data/com.termux/files/home/data/nvim/site/after', 
'/data/data/com.termux/files/home/conf/nvim/after']
```

To be correct, it should look like this instead:

```
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/conf/nvim,/data/data/com.termux/files/home/data/nvim/site,/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/nvim/runtime,/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/nvim,/data/data/com.termux/files/home/data/nvim/site/after,/data/data/com.termux/files/home/conf/nvim/after
```

I'm now I'm out of my viml-depth! my only knowledge would be to use !awk/!perl/!sed
somehow?!

*can vim handle this itself???*

either way....

**How can I dedupe my "&packpath" or "&runtimepath"?**

To those who can help, **thank you!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### packpath, the option

`packpath` is an option, which means it can be altered using the `set` command.  The `set` command *already* does de-duplication for appending values.  For example,

```
set packpath=a
set packpath+=dd
set packpath+=dd
set packpath+=dd
set packpath?
```

gives

```
 a,dd
```

It even adds/strips commas for you.  It is not always possible, but if you can, use the `set` command.

Unfortunately, `set` only looks at new values added, and offers no way to fix an existing duplicate.

#### &packpath, the variable

vim offers a read/write variable "view" into this option using the `&` syntax.  When using this you syntax, you don't get the de-duplication or comma addition.  Thus,

```
let &packpath='a'
let &packpath+='b'
let &packpath+='b'
echo &packpath
```

gives

```
abb
```

#### your example

There are two issues here, first using `uniq(` only applies to sorted arrays, thus is not guaranteed to give you a unique array, and second `string(` does not join a string with commas.

```
let newpackpath = string(uniq(split(&packpath, ',')))
```

Instead,

```
let &packpath = join(uniq(sort(split(&packpath, ','))), ',')
```

or

```
let &packpath = &packpath->split(',')->sort()->uniq()->join(',')
```

are valid solutions, except that the order of `packpath` will be altered, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: works perfectly! thank you @Mass, as for your last comment "except for the order of packpath will be altered", this is not what I want so I just removed `sort()` and its keeps the original order. thanks for a beautiful explanation!

Comment: @5c0tt, to emphasize, `uniq(` will only remove duplicates if they are directly successive.  If that works in your use-case, great!

Comment: Thank you once again! great catch!!! yes that is true in my case,  so basically it is best to use `uniq()` along with `sort()`  for succession, unless you are lucky enough that the dupes are in succession already! thanks @Mass for the amazing explanations, I really appreciate it!